# Integer division by 7

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, compiler-optimization, integer-division

Source my answer in:

[Is this expression correct in C preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260644/is-this-expression-correct-in-c-preprocessor/15261439#15261439)

I'm a little bit out of my forte here, and I'm trying to understand how this particular optimization works.

As mentioned in the answer, gcc will optimize integer division by 7 to:

```
mov edx, -1840700269
mov eax, edi
imul    edx
lea eax, [rdx+rdi]
sar eax, 2
sar edi, 31
sub eax, edi
```

Which translates back into C as:

```
int32_t divideBySeven(int32_t num) {
    int32_t temp = ((int64_t)num * -015555555555) >> 32;
    temp = (temp + num) >> 2;
    return (temp - (num >> 31));
}
```

Let's take a look at the first part:

```
int32_t temp = ((int64_t)num * -015555555555) >> 32;
```

Why this number?

Well, let's take 2^64 and divide it by 7 and see what pops out.

```
2^64 / 7 = 2635249153387078802.28571428571428571429
```

That looks like a mess, what if we convert it into octal?

```
0222222222222222222222.22222222222222222222222
```

That's a very pretty repeating pattern, surely that can't be a coincidence.  I mean we remember that 7 is `0b111` and we know that when we divide by 99 we tend to get repeating patterns in base 10.  So it makes sense that we'd get a repeating pattern in base 8 when we divide by 7.

So where does our number come in?

`(int32_t)-1840700269` is the same as `(uint_32t)2454267027`

`* 7 = 17179869189`

And finally 17179869184 is `2^34`

Which means that 17179869189 is the closest multiple of 7 2^34.  Or to put it another way **2454267027 is the largest number that will fit in a `uint32_t` which when multiplied by 7 is very close to a power of 2**

What's this number in octal?

```
0222222222223
```

Why is this important?  Well, we want to divide by 7.  This number is 2^34/7... approximately.  So if we multiply by it, and then leftshift 34 times, we should get a number very close to the exact number.

The last two lines look like they were designed to patch up approximation errors.

Perhaps someone with a little more knowledge and/or expertise in this field can chime in on this.

```
>>> magic = 2454267027
>>> def div7(a):
...   if (int(magic * a >> 34) != a // 7):
...     return 0
...   return 1
... 
>>> for a in xrange(2**31, 2**32):
...   if (not div7(a)):
...     print "%s fails" % a
...
```

Failures begin at 3435973841 which is, funnily enough 0b11001100110011001100110011010001

Classifying why the approximation fails is a bit beyond me, and why the patches fix it up is as well.  Does anyone know how the magic works beyond what I've put down here?

Comment: http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf

Comment: That pdf was very helpful in determining what the last line was for (sign fix up); however, it didn't seem to discuss this algorithm in particular, unless I missed it.

Comment: The definitive references are [here](http://gmplib.org/~tege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf) (implemented in the gcc compiler), and a follow up [here](http://gmplib.org/~tege/division-paper.pdf). Implementations can be found in the [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) library. (`udiv_qrnnd_preinv` in `gmp-impl.h`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first part of the algorithm is multiplying by an approximation to the reciprocal of 7. In this case, we're approximating computing the reciprocal with an integer multiplication and a right bit-shift.

First, we see the value `-1840700269` (octal `-015555555555`) as a 32-bit integer. If you read this as an unsigned 32 bit integer, it has value `2454267027` (octal `22222222223`). It turns out that `2454267027 / 2^34` is a very close integer approximation to `1/7`.

Why do we pick this number and this particular power of 2? The larger the integers we use, the closer the approximation is. In this case, `2454267027` seems to be the largest integer (satisfying the above property) with which you can multiply a signed 32-bit int without overflowing a 64-bit int.

Next, if we immediately right shift with `>> 34` and store the result in a 32-bit int, we're going to lose the accuracy in the two lowest-order bits. Those bits are necessary to determining the right floor for integer division.

I'm not sure the second line was translated correctly from the x86 code. At that point, `temp` is approximately `num * 4/7`, so `num * 4/7 + num` to that and bit-shifting is going to give you approximately `num * 1/7 + num * 1/4`, a quite large error.

For example, take as input 57, where `57 // 7 = 8`. I verified the below in code as well:

- `57 * 2454267027 = 139893220539`
- `139893220539 >> 32 = 32` (approx `57 * 4/7 = 32.5714...` at this point)
- `32 + 57 = 89`
- `89 >> 2 = 22` (huh?? Nowhere close to `8` at this point.)

Anyway, for the last line, it is an adjustment we make after computing signed integer division this way. I quote from the section from Hacker's delight on signed division:

> The code most naturally computes the floor division result, so we need
>   a correction to make it compute the conventional truncated toward 0
>   result. This can be done with three computational instructions by
>   adding to the dividend if the dividend is negative.

In this case (referring to your other post) it seems you are doing a signed shift, so it will subtract `-1` in the case of a negative number; giving the result of `+1`.

This isn't even all you can do; here's an even crazier [blog post about how to divide by 7 with just a single multiplication](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2010/05/optimising-pointer-subtraction-with-2.html).